# Tensorflow: how can I set `None` on argument of BasicLSTMCell.zero_state()?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I'm creating a image captioning model and here is a part of the code:

```py
.
.
.
self.img_features = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.n_inputs])
self.caption = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, self.n_steps])
self.mask = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.n_steps])

# getting an initial LSTM embedding from our image_imbedding
self.embedded_img = tf.matmul(self.img_features, self.w_img_proj) + self.b_img_proj

# setting initial state of our LSTM
state = self.lstm.zero_state(self.batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
.
.
```

As you can see above, arg of `zero_state` is set as `self.batch_size`, which is not flexible. I'd like to set it `None` so that I can pass any length of data.

How can I do this?

I've done something like `self.lstm.zero_state(self.img_features.get_shape()[0], dtype=tf.float32)` or `self.lstm.zero_state(None, dtype=tf.float32)` but it doens't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just throw in a placeholder if you don’t know its value, it can be either int, float, or **unit Tensor** representing the batch size.

Here are two ways to get the shape of a tensor:

```
tensor.get_shape()[0].value
tf.shape(tensor)[0]
```

The first one leads to a value, but the second one is a **unit Tensor**. You can verify that from [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape):

> Returns:
>
> A Tensor of type out_type.

Comment: You mean, something like `batch_size=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])`?